Weighting (rescaling) the dimensions (features) in $k$ nearest neighbors
When using $k$ nearest neighbors,one have to normalize the data set ( if X is the matrix of data such that every row represents a feature or dimension and every column represents a sample point, then it is a good option to subtract the mean of each row $i$ from every $X_{ij}$ and divide every $X_{ij}$ by the standard deviation of row $i$)
in the following question:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6786/weighted-k-nearest-neighbor-search
the following was mentioned in the second answer:
If you want to weight one dimension higher than others then I suggest you standardize all of your data so that the mean is zero and the standard deviation is one. Then you can multiply the less important dimensions by a factor (2-10) so that they appear farther away to the KNN distance metric and leave the most important dimension un-scaled
My question is about this part:
Then you can multiply the less important dimensions by a factor (2-10) so that they appear farther away to the KNN distance metric and leave the most important dimension un-scaled
Isn't it actually the opposite?
Isn't multiplying a dimension by a factor from (2-10) make it more important than the others?
For example, if we consider the following simple case: a function $F(x,y)$ when the input belongs to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Lets make two points A and B with coordinates as following
A(1,0)
B(0,1)
and let us predict the value of a point C having coordinates(0,0) by 1-st nearest neighbor.
Initially, both the points A and B have same distance from C
the points A(1,0) and C(0,0) has the same y-value 0
and the points B(0,1) and C(0,0) have the same x-value 0
now multiplying the dimension x by 2 will results in the following points
A(2,0)
B(0,1)
C(0,0)
and will make the point B more near to C than A, so the value of C will be chosen to be the value of B. note that B and C have the same x value while A and C have the same y value and the chosen value for C will be the value of B which share same x value so multiplying the dimension x by 2 makes the x value more important than y value in determining the nearest neighbor, so it makes that dimension more important.
While if we multiplies the y dimension by 2, the value of point A (which shares more near y value with C) will be chosen as the value of C.
In other words, multiplying a dimemsion x by a number>1 after  standardization will make points which have more near values of this dimension x more near to each other for the k nearest neighbors which will make this dimension more important. For example:
A(4,1)
B(1,5)
C(2,2)
dist(A,C)=√5
dist(C,B)=√10
A is more near to C, A also has more near y value to C than B to C
now multiplying x dimension by 3
we get
A(12,1)
B(3,5)
C(6,2)
dist(A,C)=6.082
dist(C,B)=4.242
B now becomes more near to C, B also has more near x value to C initially before multiplying
is this true?, or I am not getting something.
